# how to resolve Inconvertible types error in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven 3.0.5 and JDK 1.7.0_17. When i run maven using mvn install i get the following error in many places wherever conversion happens and in JBoss it's showing as Warning.

**[ERROR] \Workspace\my-app\src\controller\ChangeNoterController.java:[159,43] error: inconvertible types**

The code for the above line is:

```
                    if (resultMap != null) {
        changeNoteList = (List<ChangeNoter>) resultMap.get("changeNoterList");
        changeNoteListSize = (int) resultMap.get("changeNoterListSize");        --error
    }
```

I get the same "Inconvertible types" error in maven wherever this conversion happens in java which is showing as warning in Java.

I would be grateful if someone helps me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the method `Map.get(Object)` returns an object, it doesn't work to convert an object to `int`. Try to convert the object to an Integer. Here is the snippet,

```
changeNoteListSize = (Integer) resultMap.get("changeNoterListSize");
```

Answer (score 0):

What is `resultMap`? 
Probably that `resultMap` contains some Object without specific type for exmpl: `Map<String, Object>.`

1) When you trying parse Integer try one of this ways:

- `Integer newValue = (Integer) resultMap.get("changeNoterListSize").toString();`
- `Integer newValue = Integer.parseInt(resultMap.get("changeNoterListSize").toString());`

Maven always work better when you converting to Int from String

2) Convert to list `List<ChangeNoter>` can be tricky and in this situation try to loop through `resultMap.get("changeNoterList")` and add one by one items to `new List<>();`